# Help required: How do we create the following algebraic function over an array?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Consider two circular arrays with 12 elements each of the form:

[1, 1, 1, 1, s, -s, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[1, 1, 1, 1, -s, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, s]

where $0 \leq s \leq 1$.

We have been given one of the arrays (we don't know which). We also have a pointer that can read the value at current location and move forward and backward by any $n$ steps. The pointer currently points to one the two locations (we don't know which): 11 or 12.

Can we create an fixed algebraic function using the values of the array such that it behaves as follows:

1. It gives a non-zero output (say the value of $s$) if we are at location 11 in second array.
2. If we are at the location 12 in either of the arrays the output is 0.

We can read the values of the array using the pointer but the function has to be fixed and work for both positions and arrays. The function must be integrate-able (so no if-else conditions or symbolic functions like modulus are allowed. I reiterate the function must be integratable).

I have been struggling with this problem for days but I can't get through. Can someone please help?

The way I see is that the function must behave non-linearly over positions such that it for position 11 returns a set of positions whose entries are non-zero but for position 12 whose one of the entry is 0. Thus, we can take product of entries and we will get the required result. But, I am struggling to see how?

Comment: You said "It gives a non-zero output (say the value of $s$)", but if $s=0$ that wouldn't be non-zero.

Comment: @jjagmath yes of course. please assume output 0 in that case.